# pass variable from one domain to another via jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have two pages, lets say:

```
webpage1.com, and
webpage2.com
```

webpage1 contains

```
page.html - contains reference variables in accessing the proper data stored in webpage2.com. one reference variable may be stored in localStorage
```

webpage2 contains

```
page.html - contains the layout of the whole webpage
page.php - contains the information being worked at behind the scenes, also this guy should fetch the data i send from webpage1.
```

i know you guys may say something like ajax is the way to go. but webpage2 is already using an AJAX function on its plugin (yes webpage2 has a plugin that i need), so ajax is already not an option as for me. i also tried passing a string parameter on the url but webpage2's page.php just won't respond on $_GET when i try to fetch it.

i'm thinking of something like a variable that is capable of being shared cross domain. like for example cross-domain localStorage, or cookies, or $_SESSION.

lastly, webpage1 and webpage2 has a different server.

i hope you guys understood. thanks

Comment: `$_SESSION` is out of question, as far i know and i tried and did with passing string parameters on url  and use`$_GET`

Comment: You should be able to access the query string parameters via `$_GET`. Can you post some code?